# Win 7 64 slow file access

Tags: aptana

I have all my projects that resides on network drive (e.g. H:)
with win xp everything worked fine, after moving to win7 64 every I/O operation has become 10 times slow.
Refreshing workspace activity takes several minutes.
Any suggestion?

Comment: In the absence of any other information, I'd hazard a guess that your move to Win 7 might have coincidentally caused your network config to negotiate a slower rate. Have a look at your adapter settings.

Comment: Every other network operations e.g. File copy are very fast

Comment: Which contradicts what you originally posted. Check your adapter anyway. If possible, run your XP instance alongside your Win 7 box and gather some network/IO stats via perfmon and compare.

Comment: To be more clear..seams that only I/O operation performed inside Aptana are slow.Copyng e.g. C: to H:  or opening and davings files in other application works fine.Also using Aptana in XP virtual machine work fine